# TYPO3 filemanager to see typo3conf folder

Tags: typo3

I have typo3 7.6.18. Is it exists some filemanager extension which provide see typo3conf/ext folder ? I need edit some extension

Comment: Don't use such file manager. Don't edit extensions on the server. Use version control..

Comment: why ?? I need edit my own extension. I just have situation, I have not ftp

Comment: Urg.. I recommend to not work like this. Use git or other VCS (to develop locally) and deploy then to the server. Not even FTP is IMHO just shit. These are basics of software development. I recommend learning these bits first.

Comment: I know it and I use it. But now I have situation, I need make small edition on my own extension

Comment: Please, please refuse working with these circumstances. You'll never see a dentist working with garage tools! Minimum is FTP, best is local development.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't kneed an extension for that. Just create a new file storage which points to typo3conf/ should do it.

Comment: thanks! tell me please, how I can do it ? Create file storage

Comment: I'm more a video guy, so I do s short video for you, check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jzOecN2Ss-8

Answer (score 0):

You ca use [File Editor](https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kmcs_fileedit) extension. more information [click hee](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/kmcs_fileedit/)

Another way to create filemount and select typo3conf directory.

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/InsideTypo3Reference/CoreArchitecture/AccessControl/MoreAboutFileMounts/Index.html

Comment: Thanks! But I get this extension and I see Root and it always loading, why it not works ?